# Updating one record with variables from codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, variables, limit

I'm trying to update the the last record that matches the userid and id. With the query below, all records matching the usedid are updated. How do i get it to update only the last record for the user?

```
$sql1 = "UPDATE punch SET time=?, activitydate=? WHERE id = ? ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql1, array($data['time'], $data['activitydate'],     $data['id']));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can make two queries: first get the right ID (punch Primary Key) and second the update. Or a query with a subquery like this:

```
$sql1 = "UPDATE punch a SET a.time=?, a.activitydate=? WHERE a.id = (select b.id from punch b where b.userid=? ORDER BY b.id DESC LIMIT 1)";
```

Comment: Ok, that set me on the right path. Ended up with: 
`$sql1 = "UPDATE punch SET punch.time=?, punch.activitydate=? WHERE punch.id = (select punch.id from (select punch.id from punch where punch.id=? ORDER BY punch.id DESC LIMIT 1)AS p )";`
Thanks

Comment: @RobinBantjes If this answer helped you, please mark it as accepted. See [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more information on how to do this and why you should.